# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04 through HDMI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, 20.04, pulseaudio

I recently got a new Nvidia RTX 3070 and it seems to be working find apart from the fact that I can't play audio through the HDMI port. The audio jack on the front works fine but playing it through my monitor doesn't.
I know the monitor supports it because it works fine on my Windows partition.

The device doesn't show up in Pavucontrol, and the only sink available is the S/PDIF output on the back.

The output of `lspci` is as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ee
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43eb
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43e9
20:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
20:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
20:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
20:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
20:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
21:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5009 (rev 01)
27:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
28:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
2a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
2b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2484 (rev a1)
2c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
2d:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
2d:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
2d:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
2d:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

And the output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALCS1200A Analog [ALCS1200A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALCS1200A Digital [ALCS1200A Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I'm on kernel version `5.4.0-53-generic`.

Is this a problem with the current Nvidia drivers that I just have to wait for them to fix or do I have an issue with my configuration?

Comment: What does your asoundrc have? Also your alsa.conf Are you using Nvidia kernel driver or Nouveau nvidia driver? I am sure Ubuntu by default uses Nouveau and its better to build your own kernel disabling all them instead the ones you need. One issue could be that your channel is muted alsamixer make sure S/PDIF is mm try speaker test. I would go into Ubuntu settings there is away to enable your audio device in system settings. Listed here is no Nvidia card present. type cat /proc/asound/cards give us details of that and also lspci -k